# apache rewrite debian vs windows

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have simple rewrite rules as I just learned about them

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dl/(.*)/.*$ dl/$1/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ upload.js [L]
```

both are working on Windows for url `localhost/upload/dl/mkdji/index.php`, but on Debian works only second rule for url `www.domain.com/index.php`, but not for `www.domain.com/dl/oksoks/index.php`
After `dl` is some random string.
Obviously I'm missing something regarding directory depth, but don't know what. file htacces is in `localhost/upload` and root of domain.com folders.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need the `RewriteBase` directive. For example:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: now it's working on debian, but not windows. those two are neverending source of confusion.